# unable to update the list of items by text field in a flutter. I am not using APIs or local storage

Tags: flutter, listview-filter

unable to update the list of items by text field in a flutter. I am not using APIs or local storage. Only want to dynamically update the data on Screen.
[image]

for adding items I used this function on button onpressed function

```
binLocation.add(BinLocation(binLocation: dropdownValues,quantity: quantity));
```

and for deleting the item, I am using this line of code during the delete button onpressed in the list

```
onPressed: ()
   {
    setState(() {                                             
      binLocation.remove(binLocation[index]);
   });
  },
```

Modal class

```
class BinLocation {

  final String binLocation;   final String quantity;

  BinLocation ({this.binLocation,this.quantity});

}
```

Comment: adding and deleting items working well but unable to update the item list.

Comment: can you share code?

Comment: sure. I have updated the question.plz, check.

Answer (score 0):

```dart
// change to plural binLocations 
pluralbinLocations[index] = udpateLocation;
```

not work?
I'v tried it using `flutter demo` app, it worked

```dart
 final aa = [1];

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {.
      _counter++;
      aa[0]++;
    });
  }
```

Comment: binlocation is a list of strings. i am inserting data from text fields to list.